# Jenkins shared libraries - Loading variables

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

My project has many common variables for many other projects, so I use Jenkins Shared Library and created a `vars/buildMeta.groovy` file where I defined my variables (some `sh` parse functions), and use them at the environment stage (var1, var2):

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        // initialize common vars
        var1 = buildMeta.getVar1()
        var2 = buildMeta.getVar2()
        varA = var1 + "some_string"
        varB = var2 + "some_other_string"
    } // environment
    stages {
        stage('Some Stage') {
            // ...
        }
    }
    post {
        always { 
            script {
                // Print environment variables
                sh "env"
            } // script
        } // always
    } // post
} // pipeline
```

I decided to export the `varA`, `varB` to a shared `vars/my_vars.groovy` and use them from there (when I must to transfer the config Map with the `var1`, `var2` vars).

```
class my_vars {
    static Map varMap = [:]
    static def loadVars (Map config) {
        varMap.varA = config.var1 + "some_string"
        varMap.varB = config.var2 + "some_other_string"
        // Many more variables ...

        return varMap
    }
}
```

The thing is, for declaring those vars as environment vars I used  that way:

```
pipeline {
    my_vars.loadVars().each { key, value ->
        env[key] = value
    }
    environment {
        // initialize common vars
        var1 = buildMeta.getVar1()
        var2 = buildMeta.getVar2()
    } // environment
    stages {
        stage('Some Stage') {
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ...
} // pipeline
```

but that way the buildMeta vars (var1, var2) are nor defined yet, so I can not initialized properly the `my_vars.loadVars()` call.
On the other hand I can't duplicate the `buildMeta.groovy` functions to `my_vars.loadVars()` since there are an `sh` usage at the former, and the call for the latter is not defined under a stage (script).

I've could to solve all this by putting all those functions calls at a seperate stage (lets say 'Load Variables' stage) but I really want to avoid that dummy stage.
What is the best practice for that?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you move the block `my_vars.loadVars().each {...}` before the `pipeline {...}` block?

Comment: @DibakarAditya - I works, but it need the `var1`, `var2` vars for initializing... (that are initialized only in the environment stage).

Comment: I see. You might then need to use the Groovy syntax `env.var` or `env['var']` at the top of your pipeline eliminating the `environment{...}` block altogether. A not so clean way of using Declarative pipelines though.

Comment: The last time i saw someone do something like this it required using the extended `environment` and/or `parameters` class. The short form you are invoking is not going to be able to do this.

Comment: @Matt Schuchard, environment class is getting a `KEY=VAL` statements, how could I run an each iteration inside it?